# Close and Reopen a parent div in a vue js for loop

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

```
<div>
  <b-card-group :columns="layout == 'masonry'" :deck="layout == 'grid'">
    <b-card
        v-for="(image, imageIndex) in images"
        :key="imageIndex"
        :img-src="image"
        img-top>
    </b-card>
  </b-card-group>
</div>
```

I'm using VueJS to render this component. I have an array of image URLs in `images` data, I'm looping it over in a  component (Bootstrap Card), what I want is, I want to close the parent `<b-card-group/>` for every third iteration of the loop and reopen it again so that I can have a group of 3 `<b-card/>` inside 1 `<b-card-group/>`

So for 9 images, I will end up with 3 `<b-card-group/>` and 3 `<b-card/>` in each block.

How do I achieve this in Vue JS?

Answer (score 1):

Use a [computed property](https://v1.vuejs.org/guide/computed.html) to restructure `images` into a 3x3 array (named "`imageGroups`"):

```js
export default {
  computed: {
    imageGroups() {
      let curr = -1
      const groups = []
      const images = this.images
      for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        if (i % 3 === 0) {
          curr++
        }
        groups[curr] = groups[curr] || []
        groups[curr].push(images[i])
      }
      return groups
    }
  }
}
```

Then, use a nested `v-for` on `imageGroups` in your template to render the groups:

```html
<div v-for="group in imageGroups">
  <b-card-group>
    <b-card v-for="img in group" :img-src="img.src">
    </b-card>
  </b-card-group>
</div>
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/zYoYWGX?editors=1010)

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Bootstrap Vue, you can avoid doing it programatically and take advantage of the library's [Layout & Grid](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/layout) system.

Create one `<b-row>` and iterate the `<b-col>` elements, which will self-arrange according to the row's `cols` attribute.  You could also use different column amounts at different screen size breakpoints.

Here's an example that uses 1 column at the smallest breakpoint and 3 for the rest:

```html
<b-card-group>
  <b-row cols="1" cols-sm="3">
    <b-col v-for="(image, imageIndex) in images" :key="imageIndex">
      <b-card
        :img-src="image"
        img-top
      >
      </b-card>
    </b-col>
  </b-row>
</b-card-group>
```

No JavaScript necessary.